# download anchor tag opens file in a browser but not download it in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this in my React component where I will click a `download` to download a file:

```
<a
  key={file.attachmentId} className="item uploaded"
  href={Pathes.Attachments.getById(file.attachmentId)}
  target="_blank"
  download
>
  Download
</a>
```

My path for the file:

```
static Attachments = class {
  static base = baseApi('attachments/download')
  static getById = (attachmentsId: any) => baseApi(`attachments/download/${attachmentsId}`)
}
```

In a result, file opens in browser but not downloading.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ayka! It's not quite clear what you are asking. Do you want to download the file with a request in a React component? Could you include more of your code?

Comment: thank you, I want download file with anchor tag with path /api/attachments/download/{attachmentId}. In my program the file is opening in browser but not downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the HTTP headers to the following:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.[yourextention]"
```

It's quite common if this is a PDF, browser extensions want to read rather than download!

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you write implementation of this? please

Comment: This is to be implemented server-side (where you are hitting the API)

Comment: check out this link : [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition